# Playing Soundcloud track with WebAudio

Tags: soundcloud, web-audio-api

I am exploring WebAudio and SoundCloud for a visualization program but can't seem to get past the basic testing stage. Here's the code I used for testing but I can't hear anything. Am I missing something?

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
var context = new AudioContext(),
audio = new Audio(),
source,     
url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/204082098/' + '?client_id=(used my client id)';

audio.src = url;
source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(context.destination);
source.mediaElement.play();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is how you load the mp3 file and you forgot the /stream at the end.

This code works:

```
audioContext = new AudioContext();
var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;
source.connect(audioContext.destination);

  function SCkickOffSampleDownload( sample ) {
    var url = new URL(sample+ '?client_id=679877a8ddb9badc6a2a75373c5f3de7');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function() {
      audioContext.decodeAudioData( request.response,
        function(buffer) {
          console.log("sample loaded!");
          sample.loaded=true;
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.start(0);
      },
      function() { console.log("Decoding error! ");} );
    }
    sample.loaded = false;
    request.send();
  }

var sample = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/204082098/stream';

SCkickOffSampleDownload( sample );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/s7999f8t/

Some relevant docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData
- https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/webaudio/AudioContext/decodeAudioData
- https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/media_tutorial/web_audio_loading_data.htm

I built a sampler based on SoundCloud data, cwilso might know the UI. ;-)
You can check that here: http://www.dope-dj-culture.com

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get access to a sound across a domain boundary.  Since SoundCloud doesn't support cross-domain access with CORS, when Web Audio is connected (because Web Audio lets you inspect the bits) this will no longer work.

Comment: SoundCloud [says they do support CORS](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#crossdomain), although it's not clear if that applies to audio streams, or just to metadata requests. If they do support it for audio streams, it might be sufficient to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the `<audio>` tag.

Comment: Yes, you need the `crossOrigin="anonymous";` bit on the audio tag.